# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, error-code

although I know there's various questions looking for solutions to this error message, I've yet to find  an answer that helps me solve my code to get the comparison working, I have the code

```
def f(x,d,h,L):
    ans=0.
    if ((0.<=x) & (x<d)):
        ans=h*(x/d)
    elif ((d<=x) & (x<=L)):
        ans=((L-x)/(L-d))
    return ans

x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
h=5*10**(-3)
d=16*10**(-2)
L=64.52*10**(-2)
func=f(x,d,h,L)
```

But when I try running it I get an error pointing to the `if` line with the error code in the title, I've tried the proposed solutions given in similar questions such as using `np.logical_and` or `and` instead of `&` but all three yield the same error, please help me out

Comment: `x` is an array.  Do you want `f` to do one thing if any/all of `x` fall in one range, and a different if they don't?  Or do you want it to do one thing with the `x` values that fall in one range, and a different thing for the other `x` values?  In other words does the `if` test apply to the whole of `x` or to the individual elements?

Comment: Another way to put my question - does the function work correctly if you pass the elements of `x` to it individually?

Answer (score 5):

Use numpy.where. Optionally, use exponential notation for floating point numbers.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x, d, h, L):
    return np.where(x < d, h*(x/d), (L - x)/(L - d))

x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
h = 5e-3
d = 16e-2
L = 64.52e-2

func = f(x, d, h, L)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're focusing on the conjunction of the clauses, but it's the clauses themselves. You probably want here something like:

```
if numpy.all(0 <= x) and numpy.all(x < d):
    ...
```

See the docs for [`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html).

Comment: A possible alternative is `numpy.all((0 <= x) & (x < d)):`, but for readability reasons, I would not recommend that.

Comment: @Evert Thanks, though I actually think that the version in the answer benefits from short circuiting, while this doesn't, no?

Comment: Given `x` and the other parameters these `all` tests return `False`, meaning the `f` just returns `0.`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by defining `x` as an array an creating a cycle for evaluating every `x` individually, not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing it but I'm only working with 1000 iterations so it works well, here's what I did:

```
def f(a,d,h,L):
ans2=[]
for i in range(1000):
    if (0.<=a[i]) & (a[i]<d):
        ans=x[i]*(h/d)
        ans2.append(ans)
    elif ((d<=a[i]) & (a[i]<=L)):
        ans=h*((L-a[i])/(L-d))
        ans2.append(ans)
return ans2
L=64.52*10**(-2)
x=np.linspace(0,L,1000)
h=5*10**(-3)
d=16*10**(-2)
plot.plot(x,f(x,d,h,L))
```

Hope it solves somebody else's problem as well, and if it can be optimized to have be faster, I'd love to learn how.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the fact that an array contains more than value. For instance `a < 0` where `a = 1` has a definitive truth value (false). However, what if a is an array. eg `[-1, 0, 1]`, some elements are less than zero and some are greater than or equal to zero. So what what should the truth value be? To be able to create a truth value you have to specify if you want *all* the values to be less than zero, or for at least one value to be less than zero (*any* value).

Since mathematical operators on numpy arrays return arrays themselves we can call `all` or `any` on those arrays to see if all or at least one value is *truthful*. You would rewrite your if statement as:

```
if (0 <= x).all() and (x < d).all():
    ...
# alternatively
if 0 <= x.min() and x.max() < d:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered assuming that you want to apply one calculation or other depending on whether all/any values of `x` meet the respective conditions.  I'll make a different assumption - that you want to apply `f` to each element of `x` individually.

Applied element by element I get:

```
In [226]: x=np.linspace(0,1,20)

In [227]: [f(z,d,h,L) for z in x]
Out[227]: 
[0.0,
 0.0016447368421052631,
 0.0032894736842105261,
 0.0049342105263157892,
 0.89586497157981526,
 0.78739098364212268,
 0.6789169957044302,
 0.57044300776673762,
 0.46196901982904509,
 0.35349503189135251,
 0.24502104395365998,
 0.13654705601596731,
 0.028073068078274897,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0]
```

The vectorized equivalent:

```
In [238]: I = (0<=x) & (x<d)
In [239]: J=(d<=x) & (x<=L)

In [240]: out=np.zeros_like(x)
In [241]: out[I]=h*(x[I]/d)
In [242]: out[J]=(L-x[J])/(L-d)

In [243]: out
Out[243]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.00164474,  0.00328947,  0.00493421,  0.89586497,
        0.78739098,  0.678917  ,  0.57044301,  0.46196902,  0.35349503,
        0.24502104,  0.13654706,  0.02807307,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

I'll let you package that as a function.

---

With the parameters as given (including the full `x`), `np.all(I)` and `np.all(J)` both are `False`, meaning `f` would return `0.0` if applied to `x` as a whole.

---

```
def f(x, d, h, L):
   I = (0<=x) & (x<d)
   J=(d<=x) & (x<=L)
   out=np.zeros_like(x)
   out[I]=h*(x[I]/d)
   out[J]=(L-x[J])/(L-d)
   return out
```

Comment: Hi. your answer is more like what I'm looking for, however, how can I make this into a function of `x`? I'm trying to make an *x vs. y* plot which should look like a triangle with the left side steeper than the right one, height *h*, distance from zero to *L* and d is the distance along *x* to the point where *y=h*

Comment: I added the function version.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x,d,h,L):
    ans=0.
    if ((0.<=x) & (x<d)):
        ans=h*(x/d)
    elif ((d<=x) & (x<=L)):
        ans=((L-x)/(L-d))
    return ans

#A ajouter
f_vec = numpy.vectorize(f)
#et c'est tout^^

x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
h=5*10**(-3)
d=16*10**(-2)
L=64.52*10**(-2)
func=f_vec(x,d,h,L) #ici il faut tout de même ajouter _vec
```