# Plotting piece-wise functions in python

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a piece-wise function in matplotlib. My filtering approach (which is based on Ami's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126893/the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous-use-a-any)) does not work:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Could you fix the issue, please?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gK_inf = 7.06
gK_0 = 0.09
tauN = 0.75

gK_inf1 = 0.09
gK_01 = 7.06
tauN1 = 1.1

def graph(formula, formula1, t_range):  
    t = np.fromiter(t_range, np.float)
    gK = formula(t)
    gK1 = formula1(t)
    plt.plot(t,gK)
    plt.plot(t,gK1)
    plt.xlabel(r"$t(msec.)$")
    plt.ylabel(r"$g_K$")
    plt.show()  

def my_formula(t):
    if np.all(t>0) and np.all(t<5):
        return np.power((np.power(gK_inf,0.25))-((np.power(gK_inf,0.25)-np.power(gK_0,0.25))*np.exp(-t/tauN)),4)
    else:
        return 0

def my_formula1(t):
    if np.all(t>5) and np.all(t<10):
        return np.power((np.power(gK_inf1,0.25))-((np.power(gK_inf1,0.25)-np.power(gK_01,0.25))*np.exp(-t/tauN1)),4)
    else:
        return 0

graph(my_formula, my_formula1, np.arange(0,10,0.1))
```

**Update:**

According to @Michael advice, the error is removed, but the result is not what it must be:

[image]

Actually, `formula` and `formula1`must be plotted in ranges `[0,5]` and `[5,10]`, respectively.

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: Is the plot in the update an expected output? Then I don't get why you use `np.all` and the `return 0` for the blue curve (doesn't go to zero for t>5). Please specify in more detail what you want (besides fixing the error message).

Comment: @Michael: You're right. The logic of my code is not what it is supposed to be. I'd added a sketch to illustrate what I need, if you kindly check it.

Comment: ok so you want *one* curve. I think I get it now. I'm gonna try it and then edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `return 0` in both `my_formula` and `my_formula1` with `return np.zeros_like(t)`.

`plt.plot` expects arrays of same shape. With your input data `np.arange(0,5,0.1)` you always reach that case `return 0` which is an `int`. If you want you can think of that as an array with shape `(1,)` (strictly speaking this is not true, if you try `0.shape` you get an error). Then you try to plot one y-value with 50 x-values. Even though it might seem logical to you to just always take the same y value, this is not how `plt.plot` works. When you use `np.zeros_like(t)` you get an array with 50 zero entries and `plt.plot` knows what to plot.

---

**EDIT**

According to the update, I came up with this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gK_inf = 7.06
gK_0 = 0.09
tauN = 0.75

gK_inf1 = 0.09
gK_01 = 7.06
tauN1 = 1.1

def graph(formula, t_range):  
    t = np.fromiter(t_range, np.float)
    gK = formula(t)
    plt.plot(t,gK)
    plt.xlabel(r"$t(msec.)$")
    plt.ylabel(r"$g_K$")
    plt.show()  

def my_formula(t):
    result = np.power((np.power(gK_inf,0.25))-((np.power(gK_inf,0.25)-np.power(gK_0,0.25))*np.exp(-t/tauN)),4) *(t>=0)*(t<5)
    result += np.power((np.power(gK_inf1,0.25))-((np.power(gK_inf1,0.25)-np.power(gK_01,0.25))*np.exp(-(t-5)/tauN1)),4) *(t>=5)*(t<=10)
    return result

graph(my_formula, np.arange(0.0,12,0.1))
```

The formula applied for a certain t-value is decided with the boolean arrays `(t>=0)*(t<5)` and `(t>=5)*(t<=10)`. When they are multiplied with the float array, they are cast to `0` for `False` and `1` for `True` so it is always the right formula for the t-ranges applied. Also I changed something in the formula for 5<=t<=10: To make it look like your expected output, I had to shift the exponential function: `np.exp(-t/tauN1))` was replaced with `np.exp(-(t-5)/tauN1))`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please have a look at my update? The filtering approach does not work at all.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help.